# Windows Task Scheduler runs task one day before the schedule

Tags: taskscheduler, windows-task-scheduler

We have several .bat files being executed via Windows Task Scheduler each Saturday at the specific time. For example, one .bat file is executed at 1AM each Saturday via Task Scheduler, second .bat file is executed each Saturday at 2AM etc.

However, we've noticed that the first .bat file in the list is being executed exactly a day before the schedule. For example, the task is scheduled to run each Saturday at 1AM, however the task keeps on being executed on Friday at 1AM. We've checked whether that task is being executed from someplace else, but we couldn't find anything that may cause this issue to occur.

The PC is running on Windows 10 Pro 64-bit.

What could be the possible cause of this issue?

Comment: We are also experiencing this same symptom on a particular server, the OS is Windows Server 2016 64-bit. We have other servers with the same schedule and have not observed it there.